# How to enable brace matching for QML in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-code, qml, ide

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022. In it I have integrated Qt. So when I'm using a Qt Quick Application template for example, and I'm writing code in QML, I want to be able to see where each opening and closing bracket (curly braces) begins and ends in my QML code, for easier visual representation and understanding of my code. I get lost in all the brackets unless I see where each leads.

I would appreciate guidance on how to enable brace matching for QML files within Visual Studio 2022 or if there is a recommended extension that can provide this functionality. Thank you!

I have checked the Edit menu of Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, but I couldn't find any relevant options.

Tried looking for extensions and found a bunch, one called QML Formatter but its all for VS Code, not Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 ( for this there seems to be NONE).

Great link, but for VS Code... https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreOneti.qml-formatter

And no, I don't prefer using Qt Creator.

[Image where there is no brace matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw0mN.png)

Example of where there is:
[brace matching available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJfpY.png)